# GwtBootstrap3 - при наведении на кнопку ей прописывается style="display:none", как отключить?

Tags: javascript, java, css, bootstrap, gwt

Использую http://gwtbootstrap3.github.io/gwtbootstrap3-demo/#summernote

```
<button type="button" class="note-btn btn btn-default btn-sm note-btn-underline" tabindex="-1" title="" data-original-title="Underline"><i class="note-icon-underline"></i></button>
```

при наведении показывается подсказка и стоит увести курсор мышки код меняется на такой:

```
<button type="button" class="note-btn btn btn-default btn-sm note-btn-underline" tabindex="-1" title="" data-original-title="Underline" style="display: none;"><i class="note-icon-underline"></i></button>
```

По идее видимостью должен управлять эта запись в css:

```css
.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
    touch-action: manipulation;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Но она перекрывается стилем в самой кнопке. 
Компонент добавляется через java-код путем new Summernote();, где он заворачивается в панель и добавляется на форму.

Полный код css для данной кнопки:

```css
element.style {
    display: none;
}
bootstrap-3.3.7…in.cache.css:5
.btn-group>.btn:first-child:not(:last-child):not(.dropdown-toggle) {
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}
bootstrap-3.3.7…in.cache.css:5
.btn-group>.btn:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
bootstrap-3.3.7…in.cache.css:5
.btn-group-vertical>.btn, .btn-group>.btn {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
bootstrap-3.3.7…in.cache.css:5
.btn-group-sm>.btn, .btn-sm {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
bootstrap-3.3.7…in.cache.css:5
.btn-default {
    color: #333;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: #ccc;
}
bootstrap-3.3.7…in.cache.css:5
.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
    touch-action: manipulation;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
guigwt.css:1601
button {
    dysplay: block;
}
bootstrap-3.3.7…in.cache.css:5
button, input, select, textarea {
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    line-height: inherit;
}
bootstrap-3.3.7…in.cache.css:5
button, html input[type=button], input[type=reset], input[type=submit] {
    -webkit-appearance: button;
    cursor: pointer;
}
bootstrap-3.3.7…in.cache.css:5
button, select {
    text-transform: none;
}
bootstrap-3.3.7…in.cache.css:5
button {
    overflow: visible;
}
bootstrap-3.3.7…in.cache.css:5
button, input, optgroup, select, textarea {
    margin: 0;
    font: inherit;
    color: inherit;
}
css-part-1.css:78
input[type=submit], input[type=button], input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio], input[type=file], select, a, button, [onclick] {
    cursor: pointer;
}
css-part-1.css:36
input, textarea, button {
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
}
css-part-1.css:6
p, form, blockquote, body, html, input, textarea, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, button, dl, dd, dt {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
bootstrap-3.3.7…in.cache.css:5
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
css-part-2.css:1901
* {
    outline: 0 none;
}
user agent stylesheet
input[type="button" i], input[type="submit" i], input[type="reset" i], input[type="file" i]::-webkit-file-upload-button, button {
    padding: 1px 6px;
}
user agent stylesheet
input[type="button" i], input[type="submit" i], input[type="reset" i], input[type="file" i]::-webkit-file-upload-button, button {
    align-items: flex-start;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: default;
    color: buttontext;
    background-color: buttonface;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 2px 6px 3px;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: outset;
    border-color: buttonface;
    border-image: initial;
}
user agent stylesheet
input, textarea, select, button {
    text-rendering: auto;
    color: initial;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    word-spacing: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    text-indent: 0px;
    text-shadow: none;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: start;
    margin: 0em 0em 0em 0em;
    font: 13.3333px Arial;
}
user agent stylesheet
input, textarea, select, button, meter, progress {
    -webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
}
user agent stylesheet
button {
    -webkit-appearance: button;
}
Inherited from div.note-toolbar.panel-heading
bootstrap-3.3.7…in.cache.css:5
.panel-default>.panel-heading {
    color: #333;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border-color: #ddd;
}
Inherited from div.note-editor.note-frame.panel.panel-default
guigwt.css:1396
.panel {
    background-color: #E5E5E5;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 8pt;
}
Inherited from td
css-part-2.css:201
td, input, th, .dialog td {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important;
    font-size: 13px;
}
Inherited from table
bootstrap-3.3.7…in.cache.css:5
table {
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
user agent stylesheet
table {
    display: table;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 2px;
    border-color: grey;
}
Inherited from td
css-part-2.css:201
td, input, th, .dialog td {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important;
    font-size: 13px;
}
Inherited from table
bootstrap-3.3.7…in.cache.css:5
table {
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
user agent stylesheet
table {
    display: table;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 2px;
    border-color: grey;
}
Inherited from td.dialogMiddleCenter
css-part-2.css:201
td, input, th, .dialog td {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important;
    font-size: 13px;
}
Inherited from table
bootstrap-3.3.7…in.cache.css:5
table {
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
user agent stylesheet
table {
    display: table;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 2px;
    border-color: grey;
}
Inherited from div.gwt-DialogBox
Style Attribute {
    left: 471px;
    top: 230px;
    visibility: visible;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: visible;
    clip: rect(auto auto auto auto);
}
guigwt.css:112
.gwt-DialogBox {
    z-index: 1001;
    line-height: 1;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #405b78;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #efefef;
    box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(147, 148, 150, 0.8);
}
Inherited from body.basic
guigwt.css:1594
body {
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #000;
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
}
bootstrap-3.3.7…in.cache.css:5
body {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #333;
    background-color: #fff;
}
css-part-1.css:40
body {
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    min-width: 987px;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #000;
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    _height: 100%;
}
css-part-0.css:11
body {
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #000;
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
}
Inherited from html
bootstrap-3.3.7…in.cache.css:5
html {
    font-size: 10px;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
bootstrap-3.3.7…in.cache.css:5
html {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}

css-part-1.css:29
html {
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 100.01%;
    background: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
}
css-part-0.css:5
html {
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 100.01%;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
}
Pseudo ::before element
bootstrap-3.3.7…in.cache.css:5
:after, :before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
Pseudo ::after element
bootstrap-3.3.7…in.cache.css:5
:after, :before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Как с этим бороться?

Как это дело отключить?